# Property sessionFactory is required using Spring Java config inner classes

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, config

I am using Spring 4's pure Java config (no web.xml) but having some issues with inner configuration classes. I have multiple Spring profiles like this one

```
@Profile("dev") 
public @interface Dev {}
```

So within my DataSourceConfig I'd like to have multiple `@Configuration` for each spring profile. Something like (assume the interface DataSourceSetup is annotated with `@Configuration`)

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {

    ... // some common methods to both @Dev & @Prod

    @Dev
    public static class DataSourceDev implements DataSourceSetup {

        @Bean
        @Override
        public DataSource dataSource {
            ...
        }

        @Bean
        @Override
        public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
            ...
        }

        ...

    }

    @Prod
    public static classs DataSourceProd implements ... {
        ...
    }

    ...

}
```

With this, I can just reference one `DataSourceConfig.class` in my unit testing and change the
`@ActiveProfiles({"dev"})`.
Yet when I run the test I get an

```
IllegalArgumentException: Property 'sessionFactory' is required.
```

Full trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:101)
at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:155)
at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:100)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:319)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:212)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:232)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:175)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:202)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:65)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class com.myapp.DataSourceConfig$DataSourceDev: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'sessionFactory' is required
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:129)
at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:60)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:100)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:250)
at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:64)
at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:91)
... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'sessionFactory' is required
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.afterPropertiesSet(HibernateTransactionManager.java:329)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
... 43 more
```

But it is defined! Not sure what I am missing. Here is my Dao and implementation using the sessionFactory.

```
@Repository
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class EmployeeService implements EmployeeDao {

    @Resource
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    ...
}
```

Here's an excerpt from my WebAppInitializer

```
public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { ApplicationConfig.class, DataSourceConfig.class, WebSecurityConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { WebMvcConfig.class };
    }

    ...
}
```

And here's my test class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { ApplicationConfig.class, DataSourceConfig.class, WebSecurityConfig.class,
    WebMvcConfig.class })
@ActiveProfiles({ "dev" })
public class HomeControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mockMvc = standaloneSetup(new HomeController()).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetHomePage() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/")).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post the full stack trace. Also, show us how you run your test, don't just tell us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out. There is some issue with annotating `@Configuration` in my Config interfaces. So instead of annotating the interface, I need to annotate the implementing class. For example my DataConfigClass:

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {

    ... // some common methods to both @Dev & @Prod

    @Configuration
    @Dev
    public static class DataSourceDev implements DataSourceSetup {

        @Bean
        @Override
        public DataSource dataSource {
            ...
        }

        @Bean
        @Override
        public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
            ...
        }

        ...

    }

    @Configuration
    @Prod
    public static classs DataSourceProd implements ... {
        ...
    }

    ...

}
```

It seems strange to me. But oh well, SessionFactory is working now.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but may be the problem is because of type of session factory in the DataSourceConfig class..